# ES6/ES2015 yield within closure in a function*

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yield

Can you yield from within a closure?

```
// I want the following to work but instead I get:
//   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list(…)

function* test() {
    yield 1;
    [2,3].map(x => yield x);
    yield 4;
}

var gen = test();
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // 3
console.log(gen.next().value); // 4
```

Comment: Just no, you cannot.

Comment: What would the closure do when it was not called from "within" (by whatever definition) the generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `yield*` to pass the controll to an other iterable object 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*

You also tried to `yield` inside a non-generator function which you can't. Simply use `return`

```
function* test() {
    yield 1;
    yield* [2,3].map((x) => {return x});
    yield 4;
}

var gen = test();
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // 3 
console.log(gen.next().value); // 4
```

Comment: Notice that the `map` would be evaluated eagerly to the array in this case, I guess that's not what the OP meant to do.